# Display Iframe in CGridView inside of Yii 1.1

Tags: yii, cgridview

So the title says it all i want to be able to display an iframe for the you tube video that he has stored in the inside of the database i am doing the following and it is giving

```
 array(
            'header'=>'Video',
            'name'=>'videoUrl',
            'value'=>'<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo $model->videoUrl  ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
            'type'=>'html',
        ),
```

As type i have tried eveything like raw,html and text but it still gives me an error like this all the time.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Drive\Frameworks\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php(612) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it like below:

```
'value'=>'CHtml::tag("iframe",array("width"=>"560","height"=>"315","src"=>$model->videoUrl,"frameborder"=>"0","allowfullscreen"=>""),"")'
```

As everything in `value` will be passed into PHP's `eval()` function.

Comment: Hellom that removed the error but now nothing is getting displayed, what can it be?

Answer (score 1):

use those ext it will make you easier.

[yiitube](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiitube/)

[jyoutube](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/jyoutube/)

just call widget with the youtube video id and size if you wish.

Comment: Seems interesting but i wanted to display it in in a CGridView table so that the user cna delete it in the admin page, but thank you for sharing!

Comment: Dont really see the point of adding an extension when there is something already inbuilt, what do you think?